# how to use readalltext.trimstart to remove blank lines

Tags: c#, file, trim

I am using this statement to copy the contents of a text file into an array. Many of these text files have one or more blank lines at the beginning.  I don't want to remove all blank lines, just the ones at the top of the text file.  Can I do this using TrimStart?  If not, how could I do this?

```
txtfileary[aryctr] = File.ReadAllText(txtfile);
```

Comment: You need to include a [MCVE] with your question.

Comment: `TrimStart('\r', '\n')` should work.

Comment: *" I don't want to remove all blank lines, just the ones at the top of the text file."* Does this mean that as soon as you encounter a non-blank line, you want to keep any other blank lines in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to act on lines reading lines (`File.ReadLines`) would be more appropriate. At that point you can filter out items you don't want and create array or combine all lines to string). Filtering of initial elements done with `Enumerable.SkipWhile`:

```
 var textFileWithoutLeadingEmptyLines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
       File.ReadLines(txtfile)
       .SkipWhile(line => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)));
```

Comment: Your answer removes all the `"\r\n"` from the text.

Comment: The skipwhile removes only leading blank lines.  once the check fails the skip is no longer executed for any other lines being read.

Comment: @user7396598 And that is exactly what the OP wants.